# What is the meaning of "on each bounded disc of the complex plane"?

Tags: complex-analysis

My primary language for math is not English.

What is the meaning of "on each bounded disc of the complex plane"?

For example (from https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Uniformly-convergent_series):
"... is uniformly convergent on each bounded disc of the complex plane, ..."

More specifically, does "on each bounded disc of the complex plane" refer to the group $A=\{z:|z-z_0|\le r\}$ where $r\in \mathbb{R}$, $z_0\in \mathbb{c}$? (note that $A$ is what I would directly translate from my primary math language to "a closed circle").

Thanks.

Comment: The term "disc" (or "disk") refers to the region bounded by a circle (i.e., contained within [or possibly on] the circle). An open disk, centered at $z_0$, with radius $r$, is the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-z_0| < r\}$. A closed disk, centered at $z_0$, with radius $r$, is the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-z_0|\le r\}$.

Comment: Would "on a disc" (centered at $z_0$, radius $r$) refer to the closed disc, and "in a disc" refer to the open disc?

Comment: No, they would have to be explicit. Open disks and closed disks are just sets, so "in" could be used for either one. Note: In the US, the term is usually spelled as "disk", not "disc" (but it's readable either way).

Answer (score 1):

Every disc in the complex plane (*open or closed*) is a bounded set. A closed disc is a compact set.

Suppose that $R$ is a fixed positive number, and that $z_0$ is a fixed complex
number.

- The circle of radius $R$ centred at $z_0$ is defined by
  $C(z_0; R) := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z − z_0| = R\}$
- The *open* disc of radius $R$ centred at $z_0$ is defined by
  $D(z_0; R) := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z − z_0| < R\}$
- The *closed* disc of radius $R$ centred at $z_0$ is defined by
  $D(z_0; R) := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z − z_0| \leq R\} = D(z_0; R) ∪ C(z_0; R)$

And finally,

- A subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$ is said to be *bounded* if there is some positive number $\Delta$ such that $U \subseteq D(0; ∆)$,
  i.e., $|z| \leq \Delta$ for every $z \in U$. $U$ is *unbounded* if it is not bounded.

Comment: I think they specify their disc being bounded because sometimes the radius of the disc is allowed to be $+\infty$, and they want to be clear that they want to exclude this case.